# Best way to maintain a sorted list in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to maintain a list of blocks in JavaScript and render them in a specific order. There could be add , delete  update operations on the list. This list could hold up to 1000 objects.

At the time of render, the list should be rendered in a specific order.

I am looking for the best way to implement n maintain order/sorted list in JavaScript. I need to perform the following operations on this list : Add delete; update and search.

Is there any Jquery or any other library available that can do this?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  The TaffyDB Project is pretty slick - it's JS database of sorts that provides all of the functionality you describe.

Comment: For 1000 objects, a simple array will suffice. Sorting it whenever you need it sorted, is fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

1000 elements is not a large data set. Calling `sort` on it -- even with a custom comparator -- will turn out to be faster than implementing some data structure (skiplist, b-tree, avl, redblack,..) that will allow to access values in sorted manner without having to sort the whole collection every time that order is needed. The overhead to implement that will be too significant for such small datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own [Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) in [Javascript](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2007/07/23/writing-a-linked-list-in-javascript/) very easily.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a simple sort-lookup table. Assuming the elements have unique IDs, use something like this:

```
var myList = []
myList[position] = elementId
```

Then you manage the array, not the elements. Read out the array in its native order and write your HTML from that. The rest is simple array manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone.js might get you there. It has models, collections, and views. You can specify a sort function for collections, which keeps the collection's list of models sorted.  The collection emits signals for create, update, and delete events.  You can then write a view that renders the collection of models in sorted order when any of the create, update, or delete events are emitted. The models don't necessarily have to correspond to server-side models.